# How to import .uml file in Eclipse Papyrus?

Tags: eclipse, uml, xmi, papyrus

I have some .uml files that I need to open in Eclipse Papyrus Tool. I am copying the .uml XMI code in Papyrus Model XMI uml file but the problem is that I am not able to see any view.

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather the information after researching. It is not possible to simply recreate an eclipse papyrus only from the .UML (XMI) file. We need to have the project with .di and .notation file.
If we need to edit something in our UML (XMI) file, we need to have the project. Alternatively, simply putting the XMI on an existing model will try to copy all the artifacts under some parent class/sequence or the selected UML diagram which is of no use in most cases.